# Microsoft graph api retrieves room-mailboxes as a user

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

If i query microsoft graph api to get all users as below , api response includes users as well as room-mailbox details.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
```

Response

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users",
    "value": [
        {
            "businessPhones": [],
            "displayName": "User Alen",
            "givenName": "smith",
            "jobTitle": null,
            "mail": "smith@domain.com",
            "mobilePhone": null,
            "officeLocation": null,
            "preferredLanguage": "en-US",
            "surname": "Alen",
            "userPrincipalName": "smith@domain.com",
            "id": "1e534b05-c421-40b3-w3e4-31ddeb4b23e45"
        } ,
        {
            "businessPhones": [],
            "displayName": "my Room 5",
            "givenName": null,
            "jobTitle": null,
            "mail": "myroom5@domain.com",
            "mobilePhone": null,
            "officeLocation": "Hull",
            "preferredLanguage": null,
            "surname": null,
            "userPrincipalName": "managedroom5@domain.com",
            "id": "418d8df4-9e5c-4c42-aw23-6da827345f45"
        }
    ]
}
```

what is the reasons for behaving room-mailbox as user ?. i am using office 365 account.

Comment: that does look like its a user object in the way its being returned.

Comment: @HariKrishna--MSFTIdentity    if i add room using admin portal ,is it the proper way to create rooms ?